# How to pass access token and shop name to Shopify API Node new object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, oauth, shopify-app

I am building a public shopify app and I want to add a POST route that allows a metafield to be created.

In the `shopify-api-node` [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shopify-api-node) the following is stated:

`accessToken` - Required for public apps - A string representing the permanent OAuth 2.0 access token. This option is mutually exclusive with the apiKey and password options. If you are looking for a premade solution to obtain an access token, take a look at the [shopify-token module](https://github.com/lpinca/shopify-token)."

Here is the object that needs the `shopName` and `accessToken`

```
const shopify = new Shopify({
                shopName: 'your-shop-name',
                accessToken: 'your-oauth-token' 
            });
```

In the [Shopify Node / Express](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/tutorials/build-a-shopify-app-with-node-and-express) documentation it has you add in `/shopify/callback` route qwhich includes the the `Oauth`:

```
// Shopify Callback Route //
        app.get('/shopify/callback', (req, res) => {
            const { shop, hmac, code, state } = req.query;
            /// ... skipping over code ... ///
            request.post(accessTokenRequestUrl, { json: accessTokenPayload })
                .then((accessTokenResponse) => {
                    const accessToken = accessTokenResponse.access_token;
                    // DONE: Use access token to make API call to 'shop' endpoint
                    const shopRequestUrl = 'https://' + shop + '/admin/api/2019-04/shop.json';
                    const shopRequestHeaders = {
                        'X-Shopify-Access-Token': accessToken,
                    };

                });
             /// ... skipping over code ... ///
        });
```

Instead of using the `shopify-token module` can I access/should I access this information from the `/shopify/callback` route in the following manner (see below)? Or is there a better way to do this / can you provide examples?

**Server.js**

```
// Declare new global variables //
var accessTokenExport;
var shopExport;

// New Function //
 function exportTokens(accessToken) {
                accessTokenExport = accessToken;
                shopExport = shop;
            }
```

```
// Shopify Callback Route //
        app.get('/shopify/callback', (req, res) => {

        // Export variables to New Function
        exportTokens(shop, accessToken); 
        });
```

```
// New POST route //
 app.post("/api/createMetafield", function (req, res) {

                const shopify = new Shopify({
                    shopName: shopExport,
                    accessToken: accessTokenExport
                });

                shopify.metafield.create({
                    key: 'warehouse',
                    value: 25,
                    value_type: 'integer',
                    namespace: 'inventory',
                    owner_resource: 'metafield',
                    // owner_id: 632910392 
                }).then(
                    metafield => console.log(metafield),
                    err => console.error(err)
                );

            })
```

Comment: hi there, storing access token in Db is easy but when you receive the request on call_back_url, how do you read the the relevant access_token from DB? pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the right way to use store access token

Because `shopify/callback` url call once only when store admin install your app but access token is useful for most of the time

To use store access token for your system you can do as below

`shopify/callback` API call when your app installing by shop admin that time you can store this access token in database and when it require simply getting from your db and this access token is accessible for life time till store admin not uninstall your app

Comment: Thanks. I forgot that this had to be stored in a db.

Comment: great , if you got the solution please select as correct answer for future reference. thank you

Comment: Should I send it to the db after the request.post has been made?

Comment: You can send to db within request.post method

Comment: As far as I know when you store the access token you store it with store name for future reference. I have to raise a point for this part of answer "when it require simply getting from your db", but when a request lands on shopify call_back_url it doesn't have a store address in it, so how we can simply get this token from db for that specific store?